# Unable to update data field of Float32MultiArray std msg

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish a float array. To do this, I am utilizing the Float32MultiArray std message:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h>
    
float values[3] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::Float32MultiArray array_msg;
ros::Publisher pub("array_publisher", &array_msg);

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub);
}

void loop(){
  array_msg.data = values;
  pub.publish(&array_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

However, when I rostopic echo the publisher, the message is empty i.e. the data field is unpopulated:

```
rostopic echo /array_publisher
layout:
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: []
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321818/unable-to-update-data-field-of-float32multiarray-std-msg/) by [jkarimi91](https://answers.ros.org/users/38100/jkarimi91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-24**:
On arduino, I think you also need to set the array length, but I don't remember how to do it offhand.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-24**:
Take a look at [array section](https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays) on the limitations of `rosserial` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the arduino side, array messages have an extra variable added to their class definitions used to define their length. In our case, this means that the `Float32MultiArray` msg has a `data` and `data_length` field; in order to set the `data` field we first need to set the `data_length` field:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.h>

int array_length = 3;
float values[array_length] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::Float32MultiArray array_msg;
ros::Publisher pub("array_publisher", &array_msg);

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub);
}

void loop(){
  array_msg.data_length = array_length;
  array_msg.data = values;
  pub.publish(&array_msg);
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

For more information, see the [array section of the rosserial limitations page](https://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Limitations#Arrays).

---

Originally posted by [jkarimi91](https://answers.ros.org/users/38100/jkarimi91/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-25**:
@jkarimi91If this solved your problem, then please mark your answer as correct by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

**Comment by [jkarimi91](https://answers.ros.org/users/38100/jkarimi91/) on 2019-04-25**:
@jayess I don't have enough points to accept or unaccept my own answer